# Hover over menu list items closes the menu after exiting nested list CSS/HTML

Tags: html, css, menu, html-lists

I created a fiddle to demonstrate the problem I am facing:

https://jsfiddle.net/04o67okd/

I have a few nested lists functioning as navigation menu. If you hover over "Item 5" you will see a drop-down menu and then if you hover over "Item Number 3" you will see another drop down menu. The problem is that I can't reach items that belong to the parent of the deepest nested list that are BELLOW the deepest nested menu ( "Menu Sub Item Number 4" and "Menu Sub Item Number 4").

[image]

**Can you help me catch the problem?**

```
<nav class="navbar">
    <a class="header" href="#">Badge</a>
    <ul class="primary">
        <li><a href="#">Menu Item 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Menu Item 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Menu Item 3</a></li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Menu Item 4</a>
            <ul class="dropdown">
                <li><a href="#">Menu Sub Item Number 1 for testing</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Menu Sub Item Number 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sub Item Number 3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Item Number 4</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Menu Sub Item Number 5</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Menu Item 5</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Menu Item 6</a></li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Menu Item 7</a>
            <ul class="dropdown">
                <li><a href="#">Menu Sub Item Number 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Menu Sub Item Number 2</a></li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Item Number 3</a>
                    <ul class="dropdown">
                        <li><a href="#1">Sub Item Number 1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#2">Sub Item Number 2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#3">Sub Item Number 3</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Menu Sub Item Number 4</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Menu Sub Item Number 5</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

And belonging CSS:

```
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: Courier; font-size: 14px; line-height: 24px;
    margin: 0px; padding: 0px;
}

body {
    background-color: #EFEFEF;
}

ul { list-style: none; }

.navbar {
    background-color: #333;
    width: 100%;
}
.navbar .header {
    float: left;
    color: #DDD;
    padding: 7px 0px;
    margin-left: 15px;
    display: block;
}
.navbar a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #DDD;
}
.navbar li {
    cursor: pointer;
}
.navbar .primary {
    float: right;
}
.navbar .primary li {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
}
.navbar .primary li:hover ul, .navbar .primary li:active ul {
    display: block; 
}
.navbar .primary .dropdown li:hover ul {
    display: block;
}
.navbar .primary li a {
    float: none;
    color: #DDD;
    padding: 7px 0px 7px 25px;
    display: block;
}
.navbar .primary > li:last-child {
    margin-right: 15px;
}
.navbar .primary .dropdown {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    right: 0px;
    z-index: 1000;
    min-width: 220px;
    max-width: 320px;
    background-color: #FFF;
    display: none;
}
.navbar .primary .dropdown > li > ul {
    position: relative;
    display: none;  
}
.navbar .primary .dropdown > li > ul li:hover, .navbar .primary .dropdown > li > ul li:active {
    background: #FFF;
}
.navbar .primary .dropdown li {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
}
.navbar .primary .dropdown li:hover, .navbar .dropdown li:active {
    background-color: #ECECEC;
}
.navbar .primary .dropdown li a {
    color: #333;
    padding: 7px;
}
.navbar::after, .navbar .primary::after {
    content: " ";
    display: block;
    clear: both;
}
```

Comment: when your mouse moves out  of "Sub Item Number 3", "Item Number 3" collapse and at this stage mouse pointer is not on any submenu which also collapse the main navigation.

Comment: that's a good point

Comment: That isn't only good point, that is the main point, Let say when you are hovering `subitems`,  `dropdown`'s height increases and, now 4th item goes to `7th` position, and when you're trying to select 4th item, then submenu collapses and there is no item on `7th` position where you're currently hovering.

Comment: Yes. I get it :) Thank you!

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/bhushanwagh/04o67okd/4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can allow the third level navigation to open in right.

below is updated code.

I have added below lines.

```
.navbar .primary .dropdown li .dropdown{
    right: 220px;
    margin-top: -38px;
    position: absolute;
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: Courier;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 24px;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

body {
  background-color: #EFEFEF;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
}

.navbar {
  background-color: #333;
  width: 100%;
}

.navbar .header {
  float: left;
  color: #DDD;
  padding: 7px 0px;
  margin-left: 15px;
  display: block;
}

.navbar a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #DDD;
}

.navbar li {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.navbar .primary {
  float: right;
}

.navbar .primary li {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
}

.navbar .primary li:hover ul,
.navbar .primary li:active ul {
  display: block;
}

.navbar .primary .dropdown li:hover ul {
  display: block;
}

.navbar .primary li a {
  float: none;
  color: #DDD;
  padding: 7px 0px 7px 25px;
  display: block;
}

.navbar .primary>li:last-child {
  margin-right: 15px;
}

.navbar .primary .dropdown {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  right: 0px;
  z-index: 1000;
  min-width: 220px;
  max-width: 320px;
  background-color: #FFF;
  display: none;
}

.navbar .primary .dropdown>li>ul {
  position: relative;
  display: none;
}

.navbar .primary .dropdown>li>ul li:hover,
.navbar .primary .dropdown>li>ul li:active {
  background: #FFF;
}

.navbar .primary .dropdown li {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
}

.navbar .primary .dropdown li:hover,
.navbar .dropdown li:active {
  background-color: #ECECEC;
}

.navbar .primary .dropdown li a {
  color: #333;
  padding: 7px;
}

.navbar::after,
.navbar .primary::after {
  content: " ";
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}

.navbar .primary .dropdown li .dropdown {
  right: 220px;
  margin-top: -38px;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar">
  <a class="header" href="#">Badge</a>
  <ul class="primary">
    <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Item 2</a>
      <ul class="dropdown">
        <li><a href="#">Menu Sub Item Number 1 for testing</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Menu Sub Item Number 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sub Item Number 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item Number 4</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Menu Sub Item Number 5</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 4</a></li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Item 5</a>
      <ul class="dropdown">
        <li><a href="#">Menu Sub Item Number 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Menu Sub Item Number 2</a></li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Item Number 3</a>
          <ul class="dropdown">
            <li><a href="#1">Sub Item Number 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#2">Sub Item Number 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#3">Sub Item Number 3</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Menu Sub Item Number 4</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Menu Sub Item Number 5</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: I appreciate the suggestion. Thank you. I will consider this use but it is not a desired behavior. I will have to use javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Just a quick catch. The problem is that you give the dropdown class on "item number 3":

```
.navbar .primary .dropdown > li > ul {
    position: relative;
    display: none;  
}
```

where `display: none` is causing that you can not catch the "sub-item number 4".

Answer (score 0):

[Click here for Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/bhushanwagh/04o67okd/4)

```
.navbar .primary .dropdown > li > ul.dropdown.sub-nav {
    background-color: #ccc;
    position: absolute;
    right: 220px;
    top: 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Someone already suggested that but it is not a desired behavior, I will have to use javascript..